# Como poner una columna de datagridview editable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Estoy haciendo esta pequeña aplicación, en la que cuando selecciono el departamento me muestra a los empleados que hay en dicho departamento, las columnas de "ID", "Nombre" y la de "Puesto las agrego desde la BD y la de "Monto" la agrego manualmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que no puedo hacer editable la columna de "Monto", ya lo intente por medio de las propiedades de la columna, pero ni así, tambien lo he intentado con el siguiente codigo:

```
private void frmNuevoRegistro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvEmpleados.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvEmpleados.Columns)
            {
                if (col.Name == "Monto") col.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void dgvEmpleados_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvEmpleados.CurrentCell = dgvEmpleados.CurrentRow.Cells["Monto"];
        dgvEmpleados.BeginEdit(true);
    }
```

Pero no logro que la columna quede editable.

Comment: Gracias por aceptar la respuesta como valida y si fuiste quien la punteo gracias también por ello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad `ReadOnly`, establece  la propiedad de solo lectura, si la estableces a true, `col.ReadOnly = true;`significa que la columna será de solo lectura, lo que implica que no será editable, si deseas que sea editable, debes hacer exactamente lo contrario.

```
private void frmNuevoRegistro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvEmpleados.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvEmpleados.Columns)
            {
                if (col.Name == "Monto")
                   //Si la estableces a true la columna no será editable col.ReadOnly = true;
                  //Debes hacer exactamente lo contrario, establecerla a false.
                 col.ReadOnly = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Es suficiente, con que al momento de crear la columna como dices manualmente le establezcas la propiedad `ReadOnly`  a `false`;